# Dialog Event that First on Bot Response

Tags: botframework

BotFramework documentation refers to handling user interruption via OnContinueDialogAsync event, which first when user sends a response but before it hits the dialog.

I was wondering if there is an event that fires when Dialog completes a step but before it is returned to the user. Reason I ask is because I need to sanitize the response to the user through an additional layer, and want it to fire for all bot responses.

Answer (score 0):

[Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) was designed, and can be used, for exactly this scenario.